# how to draw a graph control in MFC VC++ Visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I need to draw a graph which can be updated continuously on WinCE platform. For that, is there any built-in control available in MFC VC++ VS 2008 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeProject has at least one [possibility](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/graph.aspx) that looks reasonable.